# Update XML file (SimpleXmlElement Object) using string

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jmeter

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.6" jmeter="2.11 r1554548">
<hashTree>
<TestPlan ...>
  <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" ...>
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">

      <elementProp name="nb.publisher_Path" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">nb.publisher_Path</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">http://mmm.com</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp> ....
```

And i want to update the URL inside: elementProp name="nb.publisher_Path"

from:http://mmm.com
to : http://aaa.com

so i have wrote the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents("C://...Testing_User.jmx"));

    $result_publisher_Path_2 = $xml->xpath('//elementProp[@name="nb.publisher_Path"]/stringProp[@name="Argument.value"]')[0];

    $result_advertiser_Path = $xml->xpath('//elementProp[@name="nb.advertiser_Path"]/stringProp[2]');
    $result_adbrooker_Path = $xml->xpath('//elementProp[@name="nb.adbrooker_Path"]/stringProp[2]');
    echo ($result_publisher_Path_2);
    (string)$xml->xpath('//elementProp[@name="nb.publisher_Path"]/stringProp[@name="Argument.value"]')[0] = "http://aaa.com";
    echo $xml->asXml();
```

so the result for

```
echo ($result_publisher_Path_2);
```

is the right URL which i want to replace, and when i tried to change it with

```
(string)$xml->xpath('//elementProp[@name="nb.publisher_Path"]/stringProp[@name="Argument.value"]')[0] = "http://aaa.com";
```

it hasn't been changed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: please simplify your XML down to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using this:

```
$result_publisher_Path_2[0] = "http://aaa.com";
```

Comment: the second example is the way to go @sanki

Comment: @sanki : Thanks sanki, the second one was correct (Y)